# In C#, what's the simplest approach to late initialize an instance field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, generics

I have a class with 5-6 fields that should be initialized once after the constructor runs.

```
 public OriginalFileProcessor(IConfigManager configManager)
        {
            this._configManager = configManager;
            this._field1 = this._configManager.GetAppSetting<int>ConfigKeys.Key1);
            this._field2 = this._configManager.GetAppSetting<int>ConfigKeys.Key2);
            this._field3 = this._configManager.GetAppSetting<int>ConfigKeys.Key3);
            this._field4 = this._configManager.GetAppSetting<int>ConfigKeys.Key4);
            this._field5 = this._configManager.GetAppSetting<int>ConfigKeys.Key5);
        }
```

But I don't like to write logic apart from just simple assignments in the constructor.

I can't use inline initialization for field1 for example since then I can't use the _configManager instance there:

```
private int readonly _field1 = this._configManager.GetAppSetting<int>ConfigKeys.Key1);
```

If I use a readonly property then I'd have to add extra code like this:

```
  private int? _field1;
        public int Property1
        {
            get
            {
                if (!this._field1.HasValue)
                {
                    this.__field1 = this._configManager.GetAppSetting<int>(Key1);    
                }
                return this._field1.Value;
            }
        }
```

Is there any simpler approach for late initialization of instance fields?

Answer (score 5):

`Lazy<T>` is a good option as suggested.

What I usually use is the following...

Providing your `_field*` is a `nullable`

In your property you can do...

```
return this.__field1 ?? (this.__field1 = this._configManager.GetAppSetting<int>(Key1));
```

**EDIT:**

Given comments discussion - why not just use a `non static approach` over `Lazy<T>`, e.g.

```
private readonly Lazy<int?> _field;
// init in ctor
_field = new Lazy<int?>(() => YourFieldInit(""));
// use in property
return _field.Value ?? 0;
```

**EDIT 2:**

And a small test to clarify the Lazy behavior:

```
public class DoLazy
{
    Lazy<int?> _field;
    public DoLazy()
    {
        // 'lazy' gets initialized - but `YourFieldInit` is not called yet.
        _field = new Lazy<int?>(() => YourFieldInit(""));
    }
    int Property
    {
        get
        {
            // `YourFieldInit` is called here, first time.
            return _field.Value ?? 0;
        }
    }
    int? YourFieldInit(string test)
    {   // breakpoint here
        return -1;
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        var lazy = new DoLazy();
        int val1 = lazy.Property;
        var val = lazy.Property;
    }
}
```

Put a breakpoint inside the `YourFieldInit` - to see when it's actually called.
Call `DoLazy.Test()` from your e.g. Main.

Comment: @CuongLe why remove your answer ?

Comment: Your approach works for nullable value types I agree but I can't rely on this approach for ref types such as string. The initialization might return null and it's still valid but in your suggestion, it will retry each time!

Comment: also I want to return int not int? so ?? can't help here.

Comment: @TheLight this is just the 'simplest' solution in similar cases. And your property approach wouldn't work either (it'd retry all over again), so I just followed that line pretty much. Then you need extra 'state'/flag for that. You can `(int)`(inside) to resolve to int.

Comment: @TheLight I edited in what I think could suffice for that case

Comment: I fail to see any benefit with using Lazy<> here whatsoever as it works fine without.

Comment: I'm just addressing your possible `null` as a result of `init` - instead of an extra flag - and you get `late initialize` as you specified. If it works great then.

Comment: Lazy means when requested right? but in your code you're initializing the _field in the constructor so I don't see any benefit of using Lazy there

Comment: your 'method' on configManager is called only later from property - and only once - see the edit, cheers